# Java code optimization, Heap size constraint (use less memory)

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm, heap-memory, heap-dump

I am facing of memory exception while running this code and the constraint is heap size. Can anyone suggest if there is a way to optimize this code further?

```
public class getCustomerList {
  public static List <Customer> retrieve() throws ParseException {
    List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
      Customer customer = new Customer();
      customer.setAge(new Integer(i));
      customer.setBirthDate((new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy")).parse("01061986"));
      customer.setName("Customer" + new String((new Integer(i)).toString()));
      customers.add(customer);
    } 
    return customers;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Few ideas that might help:

1. Make age primitive, if it already is, provide the method an `int`, not `Integer`.

```
customer.setAge(i);
```

2. Move `SimpleDateFormat` outside the loop, currently you create 100000 same instances.

```
customer.setBirthDate(format.parse("01061986"));
```

3. Do you really need 100000 same `Date` instances for every customer? If you don't, you can get away with setting the same date instance in every customer.

```
customer.setBirthDate(date);
```

4. Current name creation is very inefficient, you create `Integer` object, then create string from it(and the integer is thrown away), then create copy of said string(and throw away the initial one). Just do:

```
customer.setName("Customer" + i);
```

Comment: …and stop using the legacy `Date` class. Using [`LocalDate.of(year, month, day)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#of(int,int,int)), there is no need to parse a string and no conversions between intended semantics and instant (milliseconds since …) semantics.